# RMI server updates collection passed as a parameter but updates not seen in client

Tags: java, rmi

My program does not work, that is, it can’t list the files found. You may find an error, otherwise, I don’t know. The program does not display any errors. If you want to reproduce the situation, open two command lines under the administrator rights client and server and make javac ClientInterface.java javac Client.java then in the server make javac ServerImpl.java javac Server.java start rmiregistry then run server through java Server and client through java Client. Thanks so much for trying to help me.

ClientInterface.java

```
public interface ClientInterface extends Remote
{
    public List<String> search(final String pattern, final File folder, List<String> result) throws RemoteException;
}
```

Client.java

```
public class Client{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String host="localhost";
        System.out.println("Client is running: ");
        try{
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter directory: ");
            //C:\Users\Nikita\Downloads\New folder
            //D:\PS3 Games
            String directory=sc.nextLine();
            ClientInterface remobj=(ClientInterface)Naming.lookup("rmi://"+host+"/ClientInterface");
             final File folder = new File(directory);
             List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
            remobj.search(".*\\.*", folder, result);
             for (String s : result) {
                 System.out.println(s);
             }
             System.out.println("Files count: "+ result.size());
        }
        catch(RemoteException re){
            re.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(NotBoundException nbe){
            nbe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException mfe){
            mfe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ServerImpl.java

```
public class ServerImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements ClientInterface
{
    public ServerImpl() throws RemoteException{}
    public   List<String> search(final String pattern, final File folder, List<String> result) {
        for (final File f : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                search(pattern, f, result);
            }
            if (f.isFile()) {
                if (f.getName().matches(pattern)) {
                    result.add(f.getAbsolutePath());

                }
            }

        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

Server.java

```
public class Server
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try{
            ServerImpl locobj=new ServerImpl();
            Naming.rebind("rmi:///ClientInterface",locobj);
        }
        catch(RemoteException re){
            re.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(MalformedURLException mfe){
            mfe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java RMI:Updating client side objects in the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20703944/java-rmiupdating-client-side-objects-in-the-server) tl;dr: You can't modify parameters in the server and expect to see the changes back in your client. Return the list instead.

Comment: @thatotherguy Can you change the function search so that it is with return when you have all the different data types or is it impossible?

Comment: You can return a list of strings. I don't know what you mean by "all different data types".

Comment: @thatotherguy In my function different data types are String,File,List<String> i can't write this function with return can you please write this function with return please

Comment: You can't write a return statement?

Comment: @user207421 i tried return list<string> look function search() but my program shows Count of files:0;

Comment: Did you consider listing the *returned* collection?

Answer (score 0):

I remake fucntion search:

```
public   List<String> search(final String pattern, final File folder, List<String> result) {
    for (final File f : folder.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isDirectory()) {
            search(pattern, f, result);
        }
        if (f.isFile()) {
            if (f.getName().matches(pattern)) {
                result.add(f.getAbsolutePath());

            }
        }

    }
    return result;

}
```

and in Client.java make this:

```
 List<String> res=remobj.search(".*\\.*", folder, result);
         for (String s : res) {
             System.out.println("File:"+s);
         }
         System.out.println("Count of Files: "+ res.size());
    }
```